# PHP_SELF and XSS

Tags: php, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP_SELF and XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)

Why it's necessary to filter $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], from e.g.:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <!-- form contents -->
</form>

to:  

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>">
  <!-- form contents -->
</form>
```

in order to make it XSS-attack proof?

and:

**How can attacker reach end users other than himself using the "vulnerability" of the first form?**

Comment: Please do not post duplicates.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice?

Comment: And the answer to your second question is [here](http://bit.ly/lwwdUV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) or something similar such that a URI like `/index.php/foo/bar` is directed to `/index.php`, requesting `/index.php/%22%E3E…` can get your following data outside the `form` tag.

And as for the second question: [click here](http://bit.ly/lwwdUV).

Answer (score 1):

> How can attacker reach end users other than himself using the "vulnerability" of the first form?

The attacker can link to your site from a site he controls or an email he sends.