# how secure is dreamweaver login?

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, login-script

When we use dreamweaver to create an auto-generated Login Logout - How secure it is?

while doing this dreamweaver creates 3 folders:-

```
_mmServerScripts
_notes
Connections
```

and adds this on the login.php page:-

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/da.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "../index.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_da, $da);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_id=%s AND user_password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "int"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $da) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="login" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST" target="_self">
<input name="username" type="text" />
<input name="password" type="password" />
<input name="login_button" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also it uses the mysql_pconnect for mysql connection:-

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_da = "localhost";
$database_da = "database";
$username_da = "root";
$password_da = "password";
$dacreint = mysql_connect($hostname_da, $username_da, $password_da) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Is it 100% efficient and secure? And if not can we do some modifications to it to make it as secure as possible... Because this really makes things fast.

Comment: yes i do agree, but whether it is secure enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How secure Dreamweaver PHP login logout is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680138/how-secure-dreamweaver-php-login-logout-is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Edit:** The [accepted answer to the dupe of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680138/how-secure-dreamweaver-php-login-logout-is/9680582#9680582) (by the same author? Why?) points out two vulnerabilities that I missed: PHP_SELF is vulnerable to XSS, and falling back to `mysql_escape_string()` shouldn't be necessary (although that is not a real world concern either way.) rather than steal the points from MrCode, I encourage everyone to closevote this, and upvote MrCode's better answer :)

It's not very beautiful code, but security- and efficiency-wise, it looks pretty okay. It takes into consideration that magic quotes are phased out in PHP 6, it seems to escape all incoming form data properly, and tests for the presence of variables before accessing them.

The only thing that looks like it could cause problems is the superfluous line break here:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/da.php'); ?>   <---- here
<?php
```

that will mess with the header redirect in certain situations. I would get rid of it and just do

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/da.php'); 
      if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
```

also, instead of

```
  .... or die(mysql_error());
```

one could use

```
  ....  or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

to prevent SQL error messages from being shown in production environments.

Comment: Do really making two different php code areas make any difference?? I am unable to understand, could you please explain a bit more...

Comment: @Abhilash you can't output any data before sending a `header()` command. Those two lines send data (the line break) and that can lead to the `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...` error message

Comment: just removing that piece of code i.e. `?>` and `<?php` can solve the problem? If it is so thanks for this, because now i have something to research on :)

Comment: @Abi yes, that would fix the problem.

Comment: @Abilash the accepted answer makes some very good points, especially the one about PHP_SELF. But why did you ask a duplicate in the first place?

Comment: Actually last time i was pretty convinced that dreamweaver has some great issues in it, recently with the launch of 5.5 version and some updates they have in their blog that some changes and precautions were taken to make it as secure as it can be. As you can see the linked one contains a bit changed code than this one... Now i need your professional advice whether i should go with this dreamweaver with the explained changes or i should try exploring more.... as per you advice... You have great experience

Comment: @Abi combine MrCode's and my advice and I think you will have a pretty much waterproof solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for you help and support... i really appreciate :) Now let me do a bit homework on your all teachings... thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not such a great idea:

```
mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $da) or die(mysql_error());
```

This reveals the mysql error explanation to the client, possibly revealing details of the DB schema of your user table.

Comment: actually it is backed by error handling code... it reads a php file having code like this `define('MYSQL_NOT_EXISTS', create_error("Your PHP server doesn't have the MySQL module loaded or you can't use the mysql_(p)connect functions."));`

Comment: i removed the persistent connection

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php is a php function that returns the last mysql error.