# How to secure $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Tags: php, security, validation

I am using this code below to control pagination.  It's using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` so I wanted to know if its secure this way or what do I have to do to make `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` secure?

```
<?php 

    if($rows > 10) {
        echo '<a id=nex href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($startrow+10).'">
        Next</a>';
    } 

    $prev = $startrow - 10;

    if ($prev >= 0) {
        echo '<a id=pex href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.$prev.'">
        Previous</a>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: "*secure*" has many meanings - what's yours?

Comment: "secure" meaning $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] basically executes whats in the address bar.  I am new to PHP but i was told that $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] has to be sanitized...

Comment: there is no issue in this case, there is when you use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  as a form action. And then only if your silly enough to accept any input with out checking it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP_SELF and XSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prevent XSS attacks, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` or `filter_input()` to escape `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss) for more info.

Note also that if you start an `href` attribute with `?` and no path, the browser will append the subsequent query string to the current request, much like a relative link would append to the same directory.

I'm assuming that you're sanitizing `$prev` and `$startrow` elsewhere. The mathematical comparisons should make them safe, but if they're coming from $_GET it's a good idea to run them through `intval()` before you do anything else.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what i have on the top of the query:   //New script begin

if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) {
  $startrow = 0;
} else {
  $startrow = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pg']);
}
 
So using (int) and escaping is correct?

Comment: Passing a value through inval() or casting it to an integer with (int) yield the same result, yes.

Comment: psst: If you want to prevent injection, just remote the action attribute completely. It defaults to an empty string, which is the relative URI that represents what `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` has in 99.9% of the cases so ... .

Answer (score 10):

You should use `filter_input`: http://php.net/filter_input

```
$phpSelf = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Then use `$phpSelf` instead of the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

This is better than `htmlspecialchars`, but an ideal solution would be using a tool like http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Thanks.  Since i am new to PHP i am unsure what the difference is in using filter_input vs htmlspecialchars? can you clarify?

Comment: htmlspecialchars only converts some HTML symbols to entities, but the user can still inject foreign characters or UTF-8 special chars. filter_input with FILTER_SANITIZE_URL validates an URL link (you can also see more sanitizer types on the PHP manual) but this is also incomplete (there are complex XSS techniques that can bypass that). HTMLPurifier is even better because is written to avoid XSS and circumvent all these problems with other functions.

Comment: ok but htmlspecialchars(); would still work properly for displaying user inputs, right?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is already secure in a sense that no character can produce alterations to your HTML syntax you want to post. The only thing is the filename itself.

Normally you should use methods like `htmlspecialchars`to sanitize output prior to posting it to the browser.