# why $_POST is not changing Session?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

Hello i get crazy through a script that i would like to build.

The logic behind everything:

I have a page on that I use sessions. Now the first time a user enters the site it will look if there is a `http_accept_language`. In that case a session will be created and the preferred language will saved. If there is no setting in the browser, it will be done by hand as a default language setting. Afterwards it will be direct to the correct path.

so I have this part:

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){
        $max   = 0.0;
        $languages = explode(",", (strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])));
        foreach($languages as $language){
            $language = explode(';', $language);
            $q    = (isset($language[1])) ? ((float) $language[1]) : 1.0;
            if ($q > $max){
                $max = $q;
                $pref_language = $language[0];
            }
        }
        $pref_language = trim($pref_language);
    }
    elseif (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){
        $pref_language = "en";  
    }
$_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
$pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];
    if ($basename === "index" ){
        header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/'.$pref_language.'/'.$basename);
    }
}
```

now in case of that the session already exists i would like to give an option to change language-settings on every site. therefor i have in two different footers that will be included by php and depending from the $pref_language but all include the same part:

```
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">      
    <input type="submit" id="de" name="de"/><div>german/div>
</form>
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">  
    <input type="submit" id="en" name="fr"/><div>french</div>
</form>and so on...
```

and on top the php parser:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ 
    if (isset($_POST["de"]) ){
        $pref_language = "de";
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST["fr"]) ){
        $pref_language = "fr";
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
echo "session exist:".$_SESSION['pref_lang']."<br/>";
$pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];
var_dump($_POST);
}
```

now when calling a page and pressing the button to change the language it will echo for var_dump:

```
array(1) { ["fr"]=> string(2) "fr" }
```

but when calling the session via print_r on an other blank page, it wont have changed. even when reloading the url, it will be set back to default.

so if there is someone who could give me a hint to solve that i really would apreciate.

Comment: Crazy question.. Did you have a `session_start()` on the top of your page?

Comment: On your 2nd block of code, I'd image you mean `!isset()` because your checking whether to set the session or not.

Comment: thats how it stands there, i think. but the goal is correct. first part checks if there is a sesion, second part tells what to do if not.

Answer (score 0):

Try unsetting the $_SESSION['pref_lang'] first before resetting it, like this:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ 

unset($_SESSION['pre_lang']);

if (isset($_POST["de"]) ){
    $pref_language = "de";
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
    var_dump($_POST);
}
elseif (isset($_POST["fr"]) ){
    $pref_language = "fr";
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
    var_dump($_POST);
}
}
echo "session exist:".$_SESSION['pref_lang']."<br/>";
$pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];
var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: The only line that was added was the unset($_SESSION['pref_lang']); so if it's throwing an error it may be because of the rest of the code. What was the error it gave you?

Comment: sorry, i added a wrong bracket. nevertheless the code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if (isset($_SESSION['pref_lang']))` from where you manually set the language, it is logically useless.

```
if ( isset($_POST['de']) ){
    $pref_language = "de";
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
} else if ( isset($_POST['fr']) ){
    $pref_language = "fr";
    $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;
}

echo "session exist:".$_SESSION['pref_lang']."<br/>";
$pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SESSION) //see what this contains as well
}
```

You can also simplify the whole process by changing your forms like so:

```
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">      
    <input type="submit" id="de" name="setlang" value="de"/><div>german/div>
</form>
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">  
    <input type="submit" id="fr" name="setlang" value="fr" /><div>french</div>
</form>
```

And then the PHP can become something like:

```
if( isset($_POST['setlang']) ) {
    switch($_POST['setlang']) {
        case 'fr':
            $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'fr';
            break;
        case 'de':
            $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'de';
            break;
        case 'en':
        default:
            $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'en';
            break;
    }
}
```

*Also*, using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in your output is not good practice as people can then inject code into your page, ie:

`http://yoursite.com.com/form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(‘xss attack’)%3C/script%3E%3Cbr%20class=%22irrelevant`

See: [PHP_SELF and XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)