# What is the alternative of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Tags: php, superglobals

My current address is: `http://localhost/bookstore/bookedit.php?book_id=12`

The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable is a string `'/bookstore/bookedit.php'`,

But I would like to get the string `'bookedit.php?book_id=12'`,

Do we have any function or variable can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Following link contains all the information you need... http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Note that [PHP_SELF is vulnerable to XSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss), `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is a more secure alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` you will see all of the server variables you have available to you

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: wow, thanks for mentioning var_dump($_SERVER), first time to hear about it, it is very useful for the beginner like me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Request URI variable.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: This will also return the path, i.e. `/bookstore`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$data .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';
```