# Condition not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have been writing a script for my online game server, to fetch the user name from the db and check for its level.

The problem is that the code doesn't check for the level so any one at any level can vote and abuse my voting system.

NOTE: That voting system is based on time/date so you can only vote once every 12 hrs.

Form code:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
Please Enter Your Character Name Below, <br /><br />
After You Vote Please Relogin And Your Cps Will be Added<br /><br />
<FORM action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  Character Name: <br /><br /> <input type="text" name='CharName'><br>
<br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Vote">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Vote code:

```
<html><center>
<?php
$user = 'test'; //dbuser
$pass = 'test'; //dbpass
$host = 'localhost';    //dbhost
$name = 'zf'; //dbname

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($name, $con);

$datetime = date('Y-m-d');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `level` FROM `cq_user` WHERE `name` = '$char_name'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $char_name = $_POST['CharName'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM cq_user WHERE name = '" . $char_name . "' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastvoted) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 Hours')) . "')") or die(mysql_error());
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `level` FROM `cq_user` WHERE `name` = '" . $char_name. "'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 && $row <= 119)
        echo "This character does not exist, or you have entered the wrong name. Or you could be trying to cheat and have already voted. Or you are not level 120+.";
    else
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `cq_user` SET `emoney` = `emoney` + 100000, `lastvoted`='" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' WHERE `name` = '" . $char_name . "'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE `cq_user` SET `ip` = '$ip' WHERE `name` = '$char_name'");
?>
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132303596"></HEAD>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</html></center>
```

Thats my checker

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 && $row <= 119)
```

That's the part where my Level checker should be working the <= 119!

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0 && $row <= 119)`?

Comment: `I cant add the code here , The code posting system is kinda annoying , Confusing , so i posted it on pastebin , hope that this isnot illegal !` not posting the code here reduces drastically your chance of getting good answers as not everyone cares to open secondary pages or simple don't like following secondary pages for security reasons.

Comment: You have a mix of `$result` and `$result1` queries, or is that intentional?

Comment: Well mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 checks if the user already exits or no so if the mysql_num_rows returns 0 then it will fetch the error .. that the user doesnt exist

Comment: Have you tried a `die` instead of using `echo`?

Comment: No i didnt , And i have updated my question with a view of the code instead of pastebin , im totaly confused of what to do with the script

Comment: And have you tried `if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0 && $row <= 119)`? Using `$result1` instead of `$result`?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy [**you're also vulnerable to XSS attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)

Comment: Persistant or non persistant xss ?

Comment: I think that i have fixed the vulnerability already , thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to this, it's an associate array.

```
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 || $row['level'] <= 119)
```

also if you $result1 query is returning 1 row, you don't need a while loop here.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    }
```

change it this

```
list($row) = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
```

**EDITED**

```
<?php
$user = 'test'; //dbuser
$pass = 'test'; //dbpass
$host = 'localhost';    //dbhost
$name = 'zf'; //dbname

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($name, $con);

$datetime = date('Y-m-d');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $char_name = $_POST['CharName'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `level` FROM `cq_user` WHERE `name` = '".$char_name."' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastvoted) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 Hours')) . "')") or die(mysql_error());

    list($name, $level) = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 || $level <= 119)
        echo "This character does not exist, or you have entered the wrong name. Or you could be trying to cheat and have already voted. Or you are not level 120+.";
    else
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `cq_user` SET `emoney` = `emoney` + 100000, `lastvoted`='" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "', `ip` = '".$ip."' WHERE `name` = '" . $char_name . "'") or die(mysql_error());
?>
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132303596"></HEAD>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

your html

```
<form name="FORMNAME" action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="CharName"  />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: When i added the    list($row) = mysql_fetch_array($result1);  i found 3 HTML forms wrote instead of one , And when i only added the    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 && $row['level'] <= 119)  it didnt work still

Comment: if you `echo $result.' '$row['level'];` what do you get?

Comment: I think it works , but idk why the checker isnot working .. Is there a way we can move this conversation to private such as msn , skype etc .

Comment: before your `if (isset($_POST['button']))` put this `print_r($_POST);`  is "button" there?

Comment: Array ( ) Thats what the page printed out

Comment: How can i fix that o.O :S ?

Comment: also `$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `level` FROM `cq_user` WHERE `name` = '$char_name'") or die(mysql_error());` i don't see $char_name anywhere before that line.

Comment: your form that posts to this page has to have an `<input type="hidden" name="button" value="button" />` only then will everything in your if statement work

Comment: $char_name = $_POST['CharName'];
Its under that o.o

Comment: Putted it above it , It still doesnt work , Do i have to just copy/paste that for the $_POST to work ? <input type="hidden" name="button" value="button" />

Comment: the input tag goes in your html form

Comment: After adding the tag to my HYML form the script should work ?

Comment: it should, by the looks of things, you are not posting "button" to you php code, for everything in you if statement to work.

Comment: Is that module in your reply is the working version of my script ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check out here. I'm assuming character names are unique. If so, I'm guessing you're expecting `mysql_fetch_array()` to return one result for

```
mysql_query("SELECT `level` FROM `cq_user` WHERE `name` = '" . $char_name. "'")
```

You have `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)`, and as the function name implies, `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array, so `$row` is an array of the column values requested. Each time it's called, it iterates further over the results. If you're just expecting one row to be returned, you can call it just once (no need for the while loop). Since you're just selecting one column (`level`), the level should be `$row[0]`.

Also, the conditions in your `if` statement are mutually exclusive:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 && $row <= 119)
```

I'm guessing you meant to use or (`||`) here, because you want to check if either there are 0 results or the level is less than 119.

Therefore, it should likely be:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 || $row[0] <= 119)
```

Also, the `mysql_` functions are now [deprecated](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array). It is suggested you use `mysqli_` function or the `PDO_MySQL` extension. Your code might also be vulnerable to SQL injections as you're not escaping user input before concatenating it with your query string. Consider using [prepared/parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Not to mention that he have 3 queries that could have been resumed into a single query.

Comment: So i should edit my    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 && $row <= 119)  to be    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 || $row(0) <= 119)   Is that correct?

Comment: @Prix: Okay, so there are *at least* a few things to check out.

Comment: Yes, but `$row[0]`, not `$row(0)`. `$row` is an array, so you'll want to use brackets to access an array index, not parentheses.

Comment: When its || IT doesnt let any one vote , even if his level passes 119 , When i set it back to && and row[0] the checker doesnt work so any one at any level can still vote :S im confused

Comment: Does the character you're testing for exist, and if so, is its level greater than 119?

Comment: Am i still getting any help here ?

Comment: Is anything actually being returned for the query associated with `$result`?