# How do I display the two most recent posts in a textarea using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

My plan was to have one `textarea` at the top where you could type whatever you want and post it, then the two `textarea`'s below it would update. But I have no idea how to do this, please help!

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        mysql_connect ("10.246.16.206", "alanay_eu", "hidden")
        or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("alanay_eu") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());

        $post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']); 

        $query="INSERT INTO Posts (post) VALUES ('$post')";

        mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
    }
?>

<center>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <textarea name="post" rows="12" cols="60" spellcheck="false">
      Example Comment</textarea> <br/>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /> <br/>
      <textarea rows="12" cols="60" spellcheck="false"></textarea> <br/>
      <textarea rows="12" cols="60" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: can you please tell if there is an column in the DB which keeps the Timestamp? if yes, you can query the DB and fetch the top 2 posts

Comment: No there isn't, I'm still really new to PHP. Could I use something like SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2?

Comment: SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table ORDER BY Date DESC - edited

Comment: yes you can do SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2

Comment: Added an example for `mysqli` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the table and add a timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE Posts ADD postDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then order and limit by `postDate`:

```
SELECT post FROM Posts ORDER BY postDate DESC LIMIT 2
```

Iterate through the results and echo out the `post` inside the `textarea` tag.

**IMPORTANT**

mysql_* functions are deprecated, and should no longer be used.  Look into [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also, use `htmlentities()` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to protect against XSS.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss) for more info.

An example using `mysqli`:

```
//I usually put the connection in a separate file, and include it as needed
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT post FROM Posts ORDER BY postDate LIMIT 2"); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($post);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $post = htmlentities($post, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    echo "<textarea rows='12' cols='60' spellcheck='false'>$post</textarea> <br/>";
}
```

Comment: I implemented that code in the main PHP file and everything went blank. I added the postDate like you said also. :/

Comment: Turn on error reporting to see the errors (but remove in production environment): `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  The connection has to be updated as well:  `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: The `$link` at the end of the connect line should be `$mysqli`, sorry.

Comment: It's somewhat working, but instead of showing the two most recent, it shows the first two I created. :S

Comment: Oops, `ORDER BY postDate DESC`.  Default is ascending, which would give you the first.  Updated the answer, let me know of any other issues so I can reflect it in the answer also.