# which is good php_self or phpfilename.php

Tags: php

friends can any body tell me which is good between php_self or phpfilename.php

some persons use in form action "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" and some use "updatedata.php" which one is good and why it is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `PHP_SELF` its not really neaded the problem is if you echo that variable in a link for example you have XSS attack because all parameters are written to the site.

[PHP_SELF and XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)

Here are some cool answers. So its better to use the complete name of the file and put the parameters you need filtered behind the filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Both are doing same job.But `PHP_SELF` is takes the pathname dynamically
If we use filename.php its should be static

'PHP_SELF'

        The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would be /test.php/foo.bar. The __FILE__ constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

    PATH_INFO(Filename.php) doesn't seem to be documented...
```