# Why we use htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

Tags: php, html

In a tutorial the guy says it's important to put the PHP_SELF into htmlspecialchars() because of security reasons:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

What's insecure if you don't use it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6080022/3933332

Answer (score 4):

`htmlspecialchars` replaces characters with special meaning in HTML with &-escaped entities. So, for example, `'` becomes `&#039;`. It doesn't turn `%22` into `&quot;`, however, because `%22` has no special meaning in HTML, so it's safe to display it without modification.

If you want a form to be handled by the same URL that is used to display it, always use `action=""` rather than `action=<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` or `action=<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>`.

As you've already figured out, there are serious risks of cross-site scripting (XSS) if you use either of the `$_SERVER` variables, because they contain user input and therefore cannot be trusted. So, unless you have a good reason that you need to tweak the URL somehow, just use `action=""`.