# What is the reason of $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]

Tags: php

Does anyone know what the advantage (or security reason) is to not use the same page in the action of a PHP form.

So here is the current page specified as action:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here also but then via a super global of PHP

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The advantage is of course that it doesn't matter if you move the page or rename the file when you're using $_SERVER

Comment: [What are PHP_SELF exploits and how to avoid them](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html)

Comment: Is that seriously the only advantage? Anyway, thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in that way for security reasons. This is because you print the complete path including all parameters to your site and you have a XSS problem.

If you want to send your form to the same site you can very simple use the `#`.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```

Or type in the complete filename that prevents to add all parameters to your website.

[PHP_SELF and XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss)

Here is another Post how to secure that part.