# Changing a php variable with php?

Tags: php

Tricky title, I'm sorry I don't know the right terms for PHP stuff.

But I'm trying to get $msg to go from empty to some text upon incorrect code.

Current code:

```
<?php
$msg = '';

if ($pass === ("123")) {
    echo $msg;
} else {
    $msg = 'Wrong code';
}

$pass = ($_POST['code']);
?>

<form autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);>" method="post" target="_self" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
    <input type="password" name="code"/>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `msg = 'Wrong code';` is a syntax error.

Comment: PHP variable should start with `$` sign.

Comment: Try `$msg='wtf';` When you already know how to assign a (blank) value to a variable then how can you not know how to give it another value

Comment: Side note, when you `echo $msg` in the `if` part, it's an empty string, so you won't see anything.

Comment: Sorry boys, miss on my side. I have that $ in the actual code.

Comment: So the missing dollar sign was a red herring. What are you actually trying to do that isn't working? I know, _"I'm trying to get $msg to go from empty to some text upon incorrect code."_, but after the correction this code looks like it could do that.

Comment: and `$pass` is defined where exactly? and is coming from where? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @realsub what is $pass.and what is the error.enable error reporting.

Comment: Once again, sorry. I missed some more important code. I bet <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?> is what's wrong here. I'm not getting an error, the $msg just stays empty.

Comment: What has the form got to do with setting `$msg` to anything???

Comment: And why do people consider `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` is necessary or even sensible. **No seriously, please, someone explain that to me !!**

Comment: @RiggsFolly because there's a submit button, and once that's pressed; if the input field is empty or has the incorrect code I want it to set the $msg to something along the lines of "Try again, wrong code".  Oh and the php_self thing, because copy & paste is a magical thing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Your code has missing the `$` sign at the assignment portion of `msg`. So i list up some steps for you at the bottom of the post.

After running this you will get an warning `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: pass -- at line 3`. Because you did not define `$pass`. You use `===`, which check both type and value, and return false which means the condition goes to else portion and assign the `$msg`, after whole block the `$msg` print the `Wrong code` as output.

```
$msg = '';
if ($pass === "123") {
  echo $msg;
  } else {
  $msg = 'Wrong code';
}
echo $msg; //Wrong code
```

As you are coding in the `PHP` platform, you need to maintain some convention of variable declaration.

Rules for PHP variables: Online Guide

1. A variable starts with the `$` sign, followed by the name of the variable
2. A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
3. A variable name cannot start with a number
4. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
5. Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different variables)

Comment: Doesn't `"123"` look ugly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);>
```

is missing the closing `?`

Syntax:

```
<?php [code goes here] ?>
```

But aside of that, your use of === is testing not just the value, but also the type. Depending on how you get something in $pass [it's not shown in your code], that test could succeed or fail because "123" and 123 are not the same and/or some automatic conversion you're triggering by the 'superfluous' parenthesis you are using around it. If unsure, cast it to string and/or use the `==` instead of `===` comparison.

Ref: [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

Assign "Success" to `$msg` and it will echo that on success, otherwise you echo `$msg = 'Wrong code';` if it fails, along with checking if the POST array is not empty and everything set inside of it.

Plus, the way you have it now, would have thrown you a few notices about undefined variable/index and the POST array was located in the wrong spot along with brackets around `123` which shouldn't be there because you don't need them; it's just extra code for nothing, same for `($_POST['code'])`.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$msg = 'Success'; // or put it as empty, the choice is yours

if(!empty($_POST['code'])){

$pass = $_POST['code'];


    if ($pass === "123") {
        echo $msg;
    } else {
        echo $msg = 'Wrong code';
    }

}

?>

<form autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" target="_self" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
    <input type="password" name="code"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Or you can do it like this and using `isset()` for the `$msg` variable:

```
$msg = '';

if(!empty($_POST['code'])){

$pass = $_POST['code'];


    if ($pass === "123") {
        $msg = 'Success';
    } else {
        $msg = 'Wrong code';
    }

}

if(isset($msg)){
echo $msg;
}
```

---

I'm hoping that you're not planning on storing plain text passwords.

Use one of the following:

- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Other links of interest:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)