# is calling $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"](keeping whole php code in html) , a good way of coding?

Tags: php, html

I normally use below method whenever I have to submit a form,

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    //my code

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
     <!--my code -->
</html>
```

The reason I'm worrying is whether a user will be able to see my php code if I use my whole php code with a html file which goes directly to the user, is there a risk that user will ever be able to see my php code ?

Comment: See your PHP code? No.  `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` can be manipulated to XSS inject your page. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss

Comment: Nope. the user isn't capable of seeing your codes. but I do recommend keeping it separate. you'll get that a lot when starting OOP, esp. in an MVC pattern but don't worry about this much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `<?php ... ?>` code never leaves your server - it is parsed by PHP interpreter into raw HTML, so end user won't see anything server-related.

Answer (score 2):

User cant see your PHP code, but it is not a good way. Using an empty string is best practices and actually much safer than simply using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

When using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'`] it is really easy to inject malicious data by simply appending `/<script>` after the `every.php` part of the URL so do not use this method and stop using any PHP tutorials that suggest it.