# why my login php page is not working

Tags: php, html

This is my login page and this does not verify that user login is `true` or `false` after inserting any `password` or `username` it redirects the user to the login page again. Header location is also not working. I am new in php, so I am not sure what the issue is.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $password = $userError = $passError = '';
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username === '9155499248' && $password === 'Ben 10'){
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header('LOCATION:congratulation.php');
        die();
    }

    if($username !== '9155499248')
        $userError = 'Invalid Username';
    if($password !== 'Ben 10')
        $passError = 'Invalid Password';
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <title>Login</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
     <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
     </head>
 <body>
    <div class="login">
<h1><b>Login</b></h1>
     <form name='input' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='post'>
    <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='$username' id='username' name='username' />
    <div class='error'>$userError</div>
    <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='$password' id='password' name='password' />
    <div class='error'>$passError</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="submit">Let me in.</button>
  </form>
  </div>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem arise from here `$username = $password = $userError = $passError = '';`

Comment: Can you plz describe in detail as I mentioned above that I am new in php

Comment: You have issues with double quotes where concatenation is concerned. You need to escape some of those in the bottom section of html.

Comment: Your using your encapsulation quote inside your string. You can't do that it needs to be escaped. You should be getting errors. Use single quotes for all attributes.

Escape the `php_self`, or don't use it. With no `action` you will be directed to the same page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss

Comment: How can I do that........after a lot of research I make login page but it is not working...........and sry for my child-like question

Comment: First thing to learn when programming is how to get useful errors. Find your error log and you should have some information in there about your current issue (and probably future issues as well). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: learn to debug codes.print $username...and are they passed correctly to php

Comment: Ohk thnx.........I am trying to learn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$username = '';
$password = '';
$userError = ''; 
$passError = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
  if($username === '9155499248' && $password === 'Ben 10'){
    $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:congratulation.php'); die();
  }
  if($username !== '9155499248')$userError = 'Invalid Username';
  if($password !== 'Ben 10')$passError = 'Invalid Password';
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <title>Login</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
     <script src='js/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
     </head>
 <body>
    <div class='login'>
<h1><b>Login</b></h1>
     <form name='input' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
    <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='".$username."' id='username' name='username' />
    <div class='error'>".$userError."</div>
    <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='".$password."' id='password' name='password' />
    <div class='error'>".$passError."</div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large' name='submit' value='1'>Let me in.</button>
  </form>
  </div>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script> 

  </body>
</html>";
```

I have updated a few things,

First are those quotes `"` and `'`, you are using it incorrectly, you may recheck the answer I provided.

Second is previously you put as `if(isset($_POST['sub']))` it is wrong because your button you name is `submit` not `sub` therefore it will not work properly. Also I added a value `value='1'` in the button to satisfy the **isset** condition

Comment: Thnx a lot for your help