# How to disable XSS auditor in chrome v60 (09/2017)?

Tags: google-chrome, xss

I was reading about [PHP_SELF XSS vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss) and I wanted to test it in chrome v60, I tried to disable the XSS auditor with :

```
$ chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security  
$ chrome.exe --disable-web-security  
$ chrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor  
$ chrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor --enable-devtools-experiments --disable-features=enable-automatic-password-saving
```

but nothing worked, can you tell me how to properly disable it  ?

Comment: same here, I couldn't get it to work, however I found a workaround using curl https://security.stackexchange.com/a/230222/196025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't still tried that out because **Firefox** works best for me while testing for XSS. In case you really need to bypass the chrome auditor, here is a great article you should check and hope that helps you.:)

> [Brutelogic chrome XSS bypass](https://brutelogic.com.br/blog/chrome-xss-bypass/)

Answer (score 7):

This one (that you already tried) should work:

`chrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor`

You just need to make sure that all instances of Chrome have been killed before you run that command.

Comment: +1000 for the hint on killing all instances first. Thanks!

Comment: Work like charm awesome