# Submit the form, but do not execute the php code

Tags: php, html

I have a php file, in it the code is bellow:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'view') {

    echo "get";

    print_r($_GET);

} else {

}
?>

<html>

    <form method="get" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=view&id=4') ; ?>">
        <input type="text"  />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

</html>
```

If I click the submit, why the `echo "post";` and `print_r($_POST);` do not output to the screen?

---

**EDIT01**

I changed my code to bellow:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'view') {

    echo "if ";
    var_dump($_GET);

} else {
    echo "else ";
    var_dump($_GET) ;
}

?>

<html>

    <form method="get" action="?action=view&id=4">
        <input type="text" name="username"  />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

</html>
```

however, it do not go through the `if`, it go `else`.

the screen output is like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Because action is a GET var.

Comment: Use hidden input fields if you want it to process as a `POST`. Also escape the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080022/php-self-and-xss for more info

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry about that, i have changed to the GET method. program will not execute the if code, it execute the else.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone See my EDIT-01, bro, why it do not go through the `if` block?

Comment: Its related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear as @user3783243 has already said use hidden params, or use POST for the form: https://3v4l.org/16sCo

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ah, I see now.

Comment: That's a good dup. Didn't know HTML5 changed the functionality of the form with GETs https://stackoverflow.com/a/9882750/3783243.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this code `$_GET['action']`. This code will seek the tag with `name=action`. Since there is no tag with `name=action`, your code will enter `else` instead of `if`.

To solve this, fix your input submit tag into this.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" />
```

Comment: `action="?action=view&id=4"` is a GET request with `action` set.

Comment: oh, i see. then, it should enter the `if` part

Comment: Misread the screenshot. Either way though, this answer won't help because the value is set.

Comment: You should really re-write the answer, or delete it. Look at `$_GET['action'] == 'view'`.